# Playa - Live filter is not visible in control panel

Tags: playa

How to make the live filters visible on control panel when we publish a channel? I've added channel field and set playa as field type. But when i try to publish an entry, i cannot see the live filters near to the field. I'm using Playa 4.3.3 and EE 2.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that your themes folder is loading from the same site URL as you are using the access the control panel. I've experienced that before and it was as simple as making sure that I'm logging into the exact same domain (https vs http, www versus non-www, etc).

Comment: Yes, the JS cross-domain references are rough.  If you open your browser's dev console you should be able to see any errors that pop up there - if there is a cross-domain reference, that's the best place to find it.

Comment: The control panel and themes folder is loading from the same URL. In the browser developer console there is no error shown. I can see the following log in developer           console.                                              `content script sending message               content script-0: GetToolbarStatus tb-message.js:207
content script received reply for       content script-0: Reply tb-message.js:207
content script sending message          content script-1: GetSideBySideStatus tb-message.js:207
content script received reply for       content script-1: Reply tb-message.js:207`

Comment: Problem solved. I was not aware about the 'Filter Minimum' settings for the Field type. No. of entries in the channel was less that the 'Filter Minimum' vale set.